# Calling a JS function in a loop and specify where it was called

Tags: javascript, jquery

new to Javascript so apologies if this is a dumb question!

I'm having a hard time explaining this but I have simple thumbs up/down system like this:

```
//thumbs up down reviews
$(function addThumbs() {
    $(".vote-up").click(function() {
        var review_id = $('#review_id').val();
        var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
        if (user_id == '') {
            alert('no user id');
        } else {
            $("#flash").show();
            $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />Loading Comment...');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax-thumbsup.php",
                data: {
                    "user_id": user_id,
                    "review_id": review_id //we are passing the name value in URL
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $('#vote-up').attr('src', 'img/upgreen.png');
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});



$(function addThumbsDown() {
    $(".vote-down").click(function() {
        var review_id = $('#review_id').val();
        var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
        if (user_id == '') {
            alert('nouserid');
        } else {
            $("#flash").show();
            $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />Loading Comment...');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax-thumbsdown.php",
                data: {
                    "user_id": user_id,
                    "review_id": review_id //we are passing the name value in URL
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $('#vote-down').attr('src', 'img/downred.png');
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

And my html looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="thumbs">
        <input type="hidden" id="review_id" value="11" />
        <input type="hidden" id="user_id" value="5" />
        <div id="pluses">0</div> <div id="progressdiv"></div>
        <a><img id="vote-up" class="vote-up" src="img/up.png" alt="thumbs up" /> </a>

        <a><img id="vote-down" class="vote-down" src="img/down.png" alt="thumbs down" /> </a>
        <div id="minuses">0</div>
    </div>
    comments/likes
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="thumbs">
        <input type="hidden" id="review_id" value="12" />
        <input type="hidden" id="user_id" value="5" />
        <div id="pluses">0</div> <div id="progressdiv"></div>
        <a><img id="vote-up" class="vote-up" src="img/up.png" alt="thumbs up" /> </a>

        <a><img id="vote-down" class="vote-down" src="img/down.png" alt="thumbs down" /> </a>
        <div id="minuses">0</div>
    </div>
    comments/likes
</div>
```

If I click the second thumbs up, the first one turns green, how do I tell javascript which which img#vote-down needs to be changed?

Comment: ids are UNIQUE! You can not have the same id over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ids on a page have to be unique, you need to make the common. What you should do is use a common class to reference the element. The `this` scope will get you the element that is clicked on and you can traverse the tree to find the elements that you are after.

Switch the ids to classes and combine the logic so you only have one function.

```
$(".thumbs").on("click", "img", function (e) {
    var img = $(this),
        isUpVote = img.hasClass("vote-up"),
        thumbsElem = img.closest(".thumbs"),
        review_id = thumbsElem.find(".review_id").val(),
        user_id = thumbsElem.find(".user_id").val(),
        active = isUpVote ? "up" : "down",
        inactive = isUpVote ? "down" : "up";
    e.preventDefault();
    if (user_id == '') {
        alert('nouserid');
    } else {
        $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />Loading Comment...');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax-thumbs" + active  + ".php",  //You really should just have one php, pass up up or down!
            data: {
                "user_id": user_id,
                "review_id": review_id //we are passing the name value in URL
            },
            success: function (html) {
                thumbsElem.find(".vote-" + active).prop('src', 'img/' + active + 'red.png');
                thumbsElem.find(".vote-" + inactive).prop('src', 'img/' + active + '.png');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Your vote was not counted because of an error, try again");
            },
            complete: function () {
                $("#flash").stop().hide();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Combining logic and adding a simple check means you do not have to maintain two sets of codes that basically does the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for a complete answer. Although I'm a beginner and there are a few things in your code that I haven't dealt with before...

Comment: what is not working? Any errors? Did you swap out the ids for classes? `reviewId` and `userId` is a reference to the elements, not the value. That would be `userId.val()`

Comment: I changed the code to have the Ajax call in there, does that help?

Comment: There appears to be something wrong in the code. Firebug doesn't return anything and if I do something like this     if (user_id == 5) { alert('nouserid');  ... the alert doesn't even show for some reason.